# How to achieve two-way binding between a property in an @Observable class and the @Binding property of an object in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, observable, environment

Swift and SwiftUI community!

I'm relatively new to Swift and SwiftUI, and I've encountered a challenge with two-way binding that I hope you can help me resolve.

I have an **`@Observable`** class named **`ObservableClass`** defined in a separate file (**`ObservableClass.swift`**):

```
//  ObservableClass.swift

import Foundation

@Observable class ObservableClass {
    var textFieldString = "Initial Value"
}
```

In the main app file (**`ObservableBindingApp.swift`**), I create an instance of **`ObservableClass`** with the **`@State`** property wrapper and expose it to different views through the environment:

```
// ObservableBindingApp.swift

import SwiftUI

@main
struct ObservableBindingApp: App {
    @State var observableClass = ObservableClass()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(observableClass)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in **`ContentView.swift`**, I want to bind the **`textFieldString`** property of **`observableClass`**—retrieved from the environment using **`@Environment`**—to the **`text`** property of a **`TextField`** view. I've attempted this by prefixing the property with a **`$`** sign:

```
//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(ObservableClass.self) var observableClass: ObservableClass
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(observableClass.textFieldString)
            TextField("Write something", text: $observableClass.textFieldString)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environment(ObservableClass())
}
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

> "Cannot find '$observableClass' in scope."

And when I omit the **`$`** sign, I get:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'."

How can I successfully establish a two-way binding between a property in an **`@Observable`** class and the **`@Binding`** property of an object? It's crucial to note that the **`@Observable`** class must be accessed from the environment using **`@Environment`**.

Your guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!